# How does the space shuttle move in a vacuum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

If there is no friction in space, then how does the space shuttle boost?

According to Newton's law we move by pushing something; in space, there is vacuum, so how the space shuttle moves without friction?

Comment: Short answer: it moves forwards by casting fuel backwards

Comment: Do you mean "if there is **no** friction in space?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rocket/Thrust/Gas/Free Expansion of Gas](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91789/)

Comment: Space isn't really a vacuum, though the number density of particles is significantly less than what we have in our atmosphere.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158750/2451

Answer (score 4):

It moves by throwing matter in the direction opposite to the direction it intends to move along. (in this case, it ejects its fuel.) Applying the Law of Conservation of Momentum should make it simple enough now.